# Eclipse RCP application without Eclipse GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on a swing application. I don't want to migrate it to SWT, but I'd like to use some benefits of Eclipse RCP application. Especially, I want to use the update technology to distribute application updates.

It would be great if you knew a tutorial on how to build an Eclipse RCP application that can start a custom GUI based on Swing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uhm... I don't think you'll be able to get there with the eclipse rcp...

There's a lot you'd have to adopt, including the whole OSGI structure for your app -- if you're unwilling to change your UI toolkit you've probably already got too much infrastructure in place to want to adopt that much of the RCP.

If it's just swing your married too for whatever reason, look into the netbeans rcp.

If it's just updating you want... there's more then 1 [sparkle implementation for java](http://blog.martinreichart.com/tag/jsparkle/).

Comment: Jsparkle is still vaporware now, is it not?

Comment: Not really sure actually -- but the concept is really really easy to implement.

Answer (score 3):

Check this:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html

However, I strongly advise against using them. You will end up with a lot of issues with platform independence. If you're just aiming at Windows, you might be fine.

I agree with lscoughlin, you're getting way too much overhead for that bit of functionality. You can always try to take the bits you need out of the Eclipse/Equinox project, thereby building a leaner solution. Be aware of licensing then. Looking at some parts of the code for inspiration can be helpful too, but it's a **huge** project.

Answer (score 1):

Tough task... but you can try [**qwylt**](http://qwylt.org).

It is a framework based on Equinox (Eclipse OSGi implementation). Hopefully it will provide enough functionality for you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally your request could be realized with the new Eclipse 4. In the new model all graphical output is done with so called Renderers which render the application model into the grapical output you see with your application. Lars Vogel has a [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4Renderer/article.html) on those and Kai Tödter even did a brief article on different renderers in [JavaFX 2.0, Swing & SWT Renderers for the Eclipse 4.x Application Platform](http://www.toedter.com/blog/?p=709).

He also did a basic SWING renderer which is available on https://github.com/toedter/e4-rendering I can however not tell on how stable this renderer is and to what extent it covers all application model elements provided by e4.